# Java EclipseLink Persistence JPQL Operator: TruncateDate

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have seen several answers and documentation on how to use operators, but cannot get this to work. I want to know where I can find use case on TruncateDate OPERATOR. I have looked at the following and they are not helpful:

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.5/org/eclipse/persistence/expressions/Expression.html#truncateDate(java.lang.String)

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Functions

What I need is just a simple query that works with the TruncateDate operator. Here is my query:

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name="SprMessage.findPendingMessageIds", 
            query="SELECT s.messageId "
                  + "FROM SprMessage s "
                 + "WHERE s.inOrOut = 'INBOUND'"
                   + "AND s.messageStatus = 'RECEIVED'"
                    + "OR (s.messageStatus = 'RETRY' AND s.lastUpdateDate < OPERATOR('TruncateDate', :todayIn)) "
              + "ORDER BY s.createdDate ASC")
})
```

If I replace OPERATOR('TruncateDate', :todayIn) with :todayIn it works. Is this even possible with a parameter? My issue is I do not want to check seconds and minutes, etc. Just down to the day.

Thank you in advance for any help on the matter.

Additional information on my JPA version:

```
compile (group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'eclipselink', version: '2.5.1')
compile (group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence', version: '2.1.0', ext: 'jar')
```

I could do this in code with JODA time but I would really like to see this work in JPA for the sake of IT.

Due to a comment about database system, this is being run against an Oracle 11g database, as well as a Derby database for the JUnits which are failing.

Here is the error I am getting running:

```
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-6047] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Invalid operator [platform operator - TruncateDate] in expression.
Query: ReportQuery(name="SprMessage.findPendingMessageIds" referenceClass=SprMessage jpql="SELECT s.messageId FROM SprMessage s WHERE s.inOrOut = 'INBOUND'AND s.messageStatus = 'RECEIVED'OR (s.messageStatus = 'RETRY' AND s.lastUpdateDate < OPERATOR('TruncateDate', :todayIn, 'dd')) ORDER BY s.createdDate ASC")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.invalidOperator(QueryException.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.FunctionExpression.initializePlatformOperator(FunctionExpression.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.FunctionExpression.getPlatformOperator(FunctionExpression.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.FunctionExpression.printSQL(FunctionExpression.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.expressions.ExpressionOperator.printDuo(ExpressionOperator.java:2239)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.CompoundExpression.printSQL(CompoundExpression.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.RelationExpression.printSQL(RelationExpression.java:872)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.expressions.ExpressionOperator.printDuo(ExpressionOperator.java:2239)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.CompoundExpression.printSQL(CompoundExpression.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.expressions.ExpressionOperator.printDuo(ExpressionOperator.java:2239)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.CompoundExpression.printSQL(CompoundExpression.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.ExpressionSQLPrinter.translateExpression(ExpressionSQLPrinter.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.ExpressionSQLPrinter.printExpression(ExpressionSQLPrinter.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLSelectStatement.printSQL(SQLSelectStatement.java:1683)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DerbyPlatform.printSQLSelectStatement(DerbyPlatform.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLSelectStatement.buildCall(SQLSelectStatement.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLSelectStatement.buildCall(SQLSelectStatement.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor.buildCallFromStatement(ClassDescriptor.java:813)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.setCallFromStatement(StatementQueryMechanism.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.prepareReportQuerySelectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:1696)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.prepareSelectAllRows(ReportQuery.java:1203)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.prepare(ReadAllQuery.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.prepare(ReportQuery.java:1071)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.checkPrepare(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:901)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDatabaseQueryInternal(QueryImpl.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1124)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1144)
    at com.paychex.corp.app2app.iatosfdc.WarTransactionsHandler.getPendingMessageIds(WarTransactionsHandler.java:102)
    at com.paychex.corp.app2app.iatosfdc.WarTransactionsHandlerTest.testGetPendingMessageBatchGetsMessagesById(WarTransactionsHandlerTest.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: TruncateDate is database dependent, and is based on Sybase's TRUNC(date, year) operator, requiring input to tell it what to truncate. 
 try something like OPERATOR('TruncateDate', :todayIn, 'dd')

Comment: Thanks for the comment Chris. I did try 'day' 'd' but not dd. I just tried 'dd' and it failed again for the same reason I'll update with the error just in case.

Comment: If you had any example or better documentation you would be my hero.

Comment: The error isn't related to the parameters or usage, but shows that there isn't a TruncateDate operator defined for your target database platform class.  As mentioned, TruncateDate is specific to Sybase and apparently doesn't exist in the platform you are using - it does exist in the OraclePlatform class, so you might just need to specify the target database https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_target_database.htm   The derby platform doesn't have it though, so you'll need to define your own for that platform, or do something different.

Comment: Thanks Chris for this comment. In my findings I had concluded that these extensions for JPA were just so that there were operators that did not need to be defined in the database. I guess if that is the case, then these operators do not have any value in my opinion, as they require a database that supports them anyhow. Why wouldn't I just use the TRUNC() in the SQL statement itself? I guess since my team has already adopted the JPA way, we will have to now code some custom methods to mimic the functionality between our main code and the JPA layer.

Comment: These functions are there for legacy expression support, allowing users to build queries much like JPA's criteria queries are built.  They've been there since the beginning, when databases portability was less of a concern, and so map specific database platform functionality very closely, allowing the developer to decide what to use and when.  SQL is fine to use, but using the operator does allow you to write something underneath that might match your Derby platform without having to change the SQL query.